# Select distinct on 2 keys in mongodb?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, nosql

Is is possible to select Distinct on 2 or more keys in mongoDB? All the examples I've found only show 1 but I'd actually want to do a distinct on 2.

Comment: This might help you solving the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460885/select-distinct-more-than-one-field-using-mongodbs-map-reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the examples I've found only show
>   1

For exactly this limitation....what you want or get are two completely different things. If you need this functionality: implement a merger inside your application code.

Comment: What I want is to select all the unique records by joining all the values from 2 keys