# Select distinct more than one field using MongoDB's map reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I want to execute this SQL statement on MongoDB:

```
SELECT DISTINCT book,author from library
```

So far MongoDB's DISTINCT only supports one field at a time. For more than one field, we have to use GROUP command or map-reduce.

I have googled a way to use GROUP command:

```
db.library.group({ 
    key: {book:1, author:1}, 
    reduce: function(obj, prev) { if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("key")) { 
        prev.book = obj.book; 
        prev.author = obj.author; 
    }}, 
    initial: { } 
});
```

However this approach only supports up to 10,000 keys. Anyone know how to use map reduce to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [article](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/unique_items_map_reduce/) which explains how to find unique articles using map-reduce in MongoDB.

Your emit statement is going to look something like:

```
emit({book: this.book, author: this.author}, {exists: 1});
```

and your reduce can be even simpler than the example since you don't care about how many there are for each grouping.

```
return {exists: 1};
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it works well. but I still have difficulty finding the function of `{exists: 1}`. in my understanding it is kind of an identifier for each unique value. but I still find it strange.

Comment: Typically the value is more complex and has several fields. You could simplify this to just emit a value 1 but `{exists:1}` is more self-explanatory and will make it easier when you do want to add more fields to it later.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone faces the similar problem. This is the full solution:

**Map step**

```
map= "function(){ 
    emit(
            {book: this.book, author:this.author}, {exists: 1}
        ); 
    }"
```

**Reduce step**

```
reduce= "function(key, value){
            return {exists: 1};
    }"
```

**Run the command**

```
result= db.runCommand({
        "mapreduce": "library",
        "map": map,
        "reduce": reduce,
        "out: "result"
    })
```

**Get the result**

```
db.result.find()
```